# Exception when modifying collection in foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach

I know the basic principle of not modifying collection inside a `foreach`, that's why I did something like this:

```
    public void UpdateCoverages(Dictionary<PlayerID, double> coverages)
    {
        // TODO: temp
        var keys = coverages.Select(pair => pair.Key);
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            coverages[key] = 0.84;
        }
    }
```

And:

```
class PlayerID : IEquatable<PlayerID>
{
    public PlayerID(byte value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public byte Value { get; private set; }

    public bool Equals(PlayerID other)
    {
        return Value == other.Value;
    }
}
```

First I save all my keys not to have the `Collection modified` exception and then I go through it. But I still get the exception which I cannot understand.

How to correct this and what is causing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First I save all my keys

No you don't; `keys` is a live sequence that is actively iterating the collection as it is iterated by the `foreach`. To create an isolated copy of the keys, you need to add `.ToList()` (or similar) to the end:

```
var keys = coverages.Select(pair => pair.Key).ToList();
```

Although personally I'd probably go for:

```
var keys = new PlayerID[coverages.Count];
coverages.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);
```

(which allows for correct-length allocation, and memory-copy)

---

> What is a live sequence actually?

The `Select` method creates non-buffered spooling iterator over another... that is a *really* complicated thing to understand, but basically: when you first start iterating `var key in keys`, it grabs the *inner* sequence of `coverages` (aka `coverages.GetEnumerator()`), and then every time the `foreach` asks for the next item, *it* asks for the next item. Yeah, that sounds complicated. The good news is the C# compiler has it all built in automatically, with it generating state machines etc for you. All mainly done using the `yield return` syntax. Jon Skeet gives an excellent discussion of this in Chapter 6 of C# in Depth. IIRC this used to be the "free chapter", but now it is not.

However, consider the following:

```
static IEnumerable<int> OneTwoOneTwoForever()
{
    while(true) {
        yield return 1;
        yield return 2;
    }
}
```

It might surprise you to learn that you *can consume the above*, using the same non-buffered "when you ask for another value, it runs just enough code to give you the next value" approach:

```
var firstTwenty = OneTwoOneTwoForever().Take(20).ToList(); // works!
```

Comment: What is a live sequence actually?